# What is the degree $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt{p},\sqrt[3]{p},\sqrt[4]{p},\cdots,\sqrt[n]{p}):\Bbb Q]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

> Suppose $p$ is a prime, and $\mathbb Q$ the field of rational numbers. Calculate the value of $$[\mathbb Q(\sqrt{p},\sqrt[3]{p},\sqrt[4]{p},\dots,\sqrt[n]{p}):\mathbb Q].$$

I know it is not smaller than the least common multiple of $1,2,..., n$, but I have no idea about its exact value.

Any answer will be appreciated, thank you so much.

Comment: But how is the proof?My friends and I all 'feel' it is the case,but fail to give a proof.

Comment: Yes,good suggestion,but I think that's not sufficient for providing the proof,since each $\sqrt[k]{p}$ of the field is towering over and over.

Comment: Since $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{p},\sqrt[3]{p},\sqrt[4]{p},\cdots,\sqrt[n]{p})$ is contained in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[k]{p})$ where $k= \mathrm{lcm}(1, \dots ,n)$, the degree $d:=[\Bbb Q(\sqrt{p},\sqrt[3]{p},\sqrt[4]{p},\cdots,\sqrt[n]{p}) : \Bbb Q]$ divides $k$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: this field has a generator of the form $p^{1/N}$ for some $N$. Can you find this $N$?

Comment: Oh,i suddenly catch it!Thank you,Wojowu!Math is awesome!